# Eclipse 2019-09 is not starting

Tags: java, eclipse

I have downloaded the eclipse ZIP folder in my system(windows 10 64 bit) , copy paste it in C:/ drive and clicked the eclipse icon. It shows an error " An error has occured, please refer to the log file" . I had tried deleting .metadata folder , running command "eclipse -clean" in CMD.
In my system java 11.0.8 has installed. I checked java version it is 64bit and compiled and executed a small program through CMD , it was working fine. I have tried every method but didn't get the solution. The log file link of WriteXo is below. Please help.

https://writexo.com/bywc7f9

Answer (score 2):

The log says you have Eclipse Neon.3 (4.6.3) (`eclipse.buildId=4.6.3.M20170301-0400`), not Eclipse 2019-09 (4.13), which is too old to work with Java 11 (`java.version=11.0.8`). The current Eclipse version is 2020-06 (4.16) and works with Java 8 and higher (including Java 11).

Answer (score -1):

Don't try to run a 6 year old eclipse on a 6 month old JVM.

This is effectively a bug in JDK14 (but an intentional one, and introduced in JDK version 10). Eclipse has worked around this bug [since mid 2016](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=489958), so the solution would appear to be: Download the eclipse offered on eclipse.org right now, and this problem will go away. Alternatively, download a JDK8, for example from adoptopenjdk.net and run it on that.

Comment: Eclipse 2019-09 is not 6 years old. It was released on September 19, 2019, so it's about 10 **months** old. If the bug was fixed in mid 2016, then a version released in Sep. 2019 would have the fix, so that's not it.

Comment: ... neither is JDK-11 six month old, or equal to JDK 14.

Comment: The answer said it was a bug in the **JDK**.

Comment: @Andreas see the log; abhijeet is not running 2019-09.

Comment: Well, OP obviously thought it was (see question title), and this answer is not clear on that misunderstanding. The [other answer by howlger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63176673/5221149) says it clearly. I didn't find this answer useful at all, since you don't say why you're suddenly talking about a 6 year old Eclipse version.